# Having issues with Conditional formatting in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am working on building a weight loss calculator. I am having problems using conditional formatting in my spread sheet. I am trying to have it green if less than c2, and red if greater than c2 . c2 is performed via a v look up function. I have also tried custom function to no avail. Ideally I would like to break this down as a percentage of c2 and have yellow as well but 1 step at a time. I have tried converting to a value and an int and still it's not working correctly.
Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: Could you post an example spreadsheet so people could better understand the issue you are having? It is hard to tell when we cannot check the datatype in the column ourselves :)

Comment: solved privately via marikamitsos 
for red =AND(F15>C$2,F15<>"")
For green :=AND(F15<C$2,F15<>"")

Comment: I can't it doesn't let me. I'm too new. Says I need 15 reputation to upvote disregard got it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following

1. Select `Custom formula is`
2. Put `=F15<C$2`

Repeat once more with `=F15>C$2`

To avoid formatting empty cells use `=AND(G14<F$3,G14<>"")`

Comment: Sorry it's still not working. This is the equation I used for c2 : =(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet2!A2:B6,2,FALSE))*A2

Comment: I do not understand why you want `VLOOKUP`. Have you tried the given answer?

Comment: If still having issues read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: I have tried the given answer yes , its not reading the values properly, I used vlookup to create c2 which is why I think it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Desired result you should use 2 conditional formatting rules with 2 different formulas, for the same range `F11:F`

> Formula **1** to Highlight the range `F11:F` the "Calories" column with **Green**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F11:F="",,F11:F<$C$2))
```

> Formula  **2** to Highlight the range `F11:F` the "Calories" column with **Red**

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(F11:F="",,F11:F>$C$2))
```

Since you didn't provide the sheet i did recreate it from scratch.

[image]

**Explanation**

[`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en) Range `F11:F` is Empty "" Do nothing `,,` if isn't Empty check if `F11:F < $C$2` in case of green formula 1 and check `F11:F > $C$2` in case of red formula 2 if TRUE Highlight green / red if FALSE do nothing.

[`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en) allow the usage of non-array functions with arrays and the ability to show values returned by an array formula over many rows and/or columns.